# generate spherical arc coordinates

Tags: c++, math, coordinates, computational-geometry

I want to generate a vector of spherical (Earth) coordinates that would draw an arc given center location (in longitude latitude), radius (in meters), azimuth, and angle width (in radians).

My code:

```
double left = azimuth - width * .5;
double right = azimuth + width * .5;
double angleStep = 0.05;
std::vector<double> arcPointsX, arcPointsY;

for (double f = left; f <= right; f += angleStep) {   
    arcPointsX.push_back(x + radius * (double)cos(f));
    arcPointsY.push_back(y + radius * (double)sin(f));
}
```

This produces arcs however, these arcs are not facing the correct direction when I draw them though.

Thanks for help!

Comment: How are you using `xa1`, `ya1`, `xa2`, and `ya2`?

Comment: same way as arcPointsX and arcPointsY, they should not really be there, I will modify the code.

Comment: What are X and Y? You seem to be drawing an arc in the plane passing through the equator, not the surface of the Earth.

Comment: X,Y is the circle center location in longitude latitude

Comment: You're trying to do too much at once. Are you comfortable with coordinate conversions between spherical (lat, lon) and Cartesian (x,y,z)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem was I had sin/cos the other way around. Using this gives me correct arcs:

```
arcPointsX.push_back(x + radius * (double)sin(f));
arcPointsY.push_back(y + radius * (double)cos(f));
```